# Ways of using(assigning) variables in Sage

Tags: math, sage, boolean-algebra

I need to test an n-variable Boolean Function `f = f(x0,...,xn-1)`. I need to fix x0, then run some tests for the `g1 = f(x1,...,xn-1)`, then fix x1 and so on.
The problem is that I don't really understand how to do it with Sage.

At first, I tried to create a vector of values, that controls "fixing" of the variables

```
R.<x0,x1,x2,x3> = BooleanPolynomialRing()

v = [None,1,None, 0]

if v[0] != None:
    x0=v[0]
if v[1] != None:
    x1=v[1]
if v[2] != None:
    x2=v[2]
if v[3] != None:
    x3=v[3]

f = BooleanFunction(x0+x3+x0*x1+x0*x1*x2)


print(f.algebraic_normal_form())

output:x0*x2
```

This works fine, but it doesn't fit my task because I want to be able to automate the fixing process.
I want to replace the "`if`"s with a loop, but in this case, I don't know how to address variables inside the loop using indexes.

I'm new to Sage so I would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `BooleanFunction` is, but:

```
sage: R.<x0, x1, x2, x3> = BooleanPolynomialRing()
```

If at this point you do something like `x1 = 1`, then `x1` is no longer a generator of this ring, so let's try to avoid that.

```
sage: f = x0 + x3 + x0*x1 + x0*x1*x2  # f is in R
sage: f.substitute({x1: 1})
x0*x2 + x3
```

I think what you want is a good way to carry out the `substitute` part of this.
A helpful observation: you can convert strings to variable names:

```
sage: R('x0')
x0
```

So:

```
sage: d = {}
sage: for i in range(len(v)): 
....:     if v[i] is not None: 
....:         d[R('x' + str(i))] = v[i] 
....:
sage: d
{x1: 1, x3: 0}
sage: f.substitute(d)
x0*x2
```

The code can now be made more compact in two ways.

Call `x` the list of generators and use `x[i]` rather than `R('x' + str(i)')`:

```
sage: R.<x0, x1, x2, x3> = BooleanPolynomialRing()
sage: x = R.gens()
sage: x[0]*x[3] + x[1]*x[2]*x[3]
x0*x3 + x1*x2*x3
```

Use comprehension syntax rather than empty dictionary and for loop:

```
sage: f = x0 + x3 + x0*x1 + x0*x1*x2
sage: v = [None, 1, None, 0]
sage: f.subs({x[i]: vi for i, vi in enumerate(v) if vi is not None})
x0*x2
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. I though that without ```BooleanFunction``` I can't not create a boolean function by its ANF. Fun fact: you can't use ```f.subs``` if ```f``` is a ```BooleanFunction```, but you can use it if have written just like you did.